# Batch script - concatenate sequential numbers on files to keep the names unique

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I'm working on a script for copying files in a folder which corresponds to the file's name and I have that part worked out using a FOR loop which checks to make sure the destination folder exists and copies the files once it has verified that it does. Example: 11-01111_ABC_DEF.pdf would go into /11/0111/. The length may vary by one or two characters but the format is consistent. I've copied my basic script below.

My problem is that sometimes a file with the same name needs to be processed. How could I go about concatenating a number to the end of the file if one or more copies of the file already exists in the destination folder?

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.PDF *.TXT) do (
  set "source="C:\files"
  set "dest=R:\"  
  set "filename=%%x"
  set "prefix=!filename:~0,2!"
  set "folder=!filename:~3,5!"

  if not exist !dest!\!prefix!\!folder! MOVE !filename! !source!\failed 
  if exist !source!\!filename! MOVE !filename! !dest!\!prefix!\!folder! 
)
```

Comment: Try using `forfiles` if you have windows 7 (I find it very useful)

Comment: Could you add a date and timestamp to the end of the name of the copied file, if it already exists?  Would that be appropriate in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "dest=worked"
for %%i in (*.pdf *.txt) do (
   for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=-_." %%j in ("%%i") do (
      if exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k" if exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%i" if exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%j-%%k-1_%%l_%%m" (
     for /f "tokens=1-9* delims=-_." %%n in ('dir %dest%\%%j\%%k\%%j-%%k*-* /b') do set /a inc=%%p
     set /a inc+=1
     move "%%i" "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%j-%%k-!inc!_%%l_%%m" || move "%%~i" "failed"
     set inc=
     )
      if exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%i" if not exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%j-%%k-1_%%l_%%m" (
     move "%%i" "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%j-%%k-1_%%l_%%m" || move "%%~i" "failed"
     )
      if exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k" if not exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%~i" (
     move "%%~i" "%dest%\%%j\%%k\%%~i" || move "%%~i" "failed"
     )
      if not exist "%dest%\%%j\%%k" move "%%~i" "failed"
      )
)
```

put this in the folder with the .txts and .pdfs comment if you want me to change something.

Comment: This script looks really good. One problem I noted when testing is that %%k seems to be getting assigned everything after the dash. I've pasted an example below.                                                  (
if exist C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\13\01111_BOL_ETC if exist C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\13\01111_BOL_ETC\13-01111_BOL_ETC.txt (
move "13-01111_BOL_ETC.txt" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\13\01111_BOL_ETC\13-
01111_BOL_ETC!a!.txt"
 set /a a+=1
)

Comment: look at line 5. the delims are - and . so it will grab everything in-between the - and . ;) change the . to whatever you want the second delimiter to be, I chose . for the extension.

Comment: That works. I noticed something else too. On the first run with some test files it copies them normally. Running it with another copy of those files it appends a 1 to the first duplicate file it copies and then 2,3, and 4 to the second third and fourth files even though they have different file names.

Comment: yes, that was to generate different file names for each duplicate, not necessarily for each file name. if you need it to do it differently tell me and I'll change it.

Comment: Ideally the appended number would be increased for each file name if that file exists instead of whenever there was an existing file found for any file name. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works but it can't append anything beyond "-1", the 3rd identical file doesn't get a "-2" for example. Aside from that, it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: That increments and renames perfectly. There are 2 tweaks I'm wondering about though. Can the incrementing number be moved to 13-11111_ABC-1_DEF or at the end? I tried that and it broke the script so I missed something I'm sure. The other thing is, can it account for a file named something like this 13-11111-1_ABC-3_DEF where it would need to go into a folder named 11111-1 instead of 11111? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: the first one is not to hard... I'll get on it. the second one, I am not so sure about. if you could explain when that would pop up, I would much appreciate it, because that would help to know how to deal with it.

Comment: It wouldn't occur most of the time. It would just be that it's related but separate and would be designated by the second hyphen with a 1 "-1". So 13-01111_ABC_DEF.txt and 13-01111-1_ABC_DEF.txt would have their own individual folders. Files with the -1 may just need to be set aside for manual moving if necessary.

Comment: I'll get to work see if I can do it... I am thirteen and still in high-school so I probably won't finish it today, I will try for tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate all of the work and tweaking of the script you've done.

Comment: Hey Nephi, no need to bother with the extra -1 being handled differently. If you can move where the number is appended though that should be it.

Comment: look. I am Reeallly busy. I am trying to do eighth grade in a fifth of the normal time, and it means working from 8:00 am to 9:00 pm. I will write the code Friday and Saturday, that is less busy.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to post an update since the changes necessary were more simple than I had previously posted.

Comment: Another note. In the currently posted code, it can't increment past 10. See the output from the end of the script below. It, presumably, overwrites 9 after a file with -10 is created.                                                      set /a inc=10

set /a inc=1

set /a inc=2

set /a inc=3

set /a inc=4

set /a inc=5

set /a inc=6

set /a inc=7

set /a inc=8

set /a inc=9

Comment: Hey @Nephi, I know you're busy with school but have you had a chance to revise the script? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to fix the overwriting 10 prob. You see, in the directory listing the output is sorted by character so that whatever9.txt comes after whatever10.txt because the 1 is < the 9. Sorry it is taking so long, but I just finished eighth grade yesterday so I have time today. thanks for waiting... ;)

Comment: Hey @Nephi, have you had any success?

Comment: no. i dont think it is possible to match a variable number of digits, and the only other place i can put the number is after the extension. im really sorry.

Comment: Thank you for trying, I really appreciate it. I'll take a look at other scripting languages to see if something like this can be done.

Comment: id suggest python, or vbscript if you just want windows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.